# "I needed to tell" vs "I needed to have told"

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple

What is the difference between the two sentences:

1. I needed to tell you something.
2. I needed to have told you something.

And how does this "**to have done**" work? Can we use it with all verbs?

Comment: #1 sounds like fluent, idiomatic speech, while #2 sounds awful. I could readily accept _I should have told you something_, but I don't like the wording in your question. (I'm not sure how that assessment projects onto other verbs, though, which is why I'm only commenting for now.)

Comment: What about "**meant**"? "*I meant to have told you*" vs "*I meant to tell you*".

Comment: Why would you opt for _I meant to have told you_ when you can use the more natural and less clunky _I meant to tell you_?

Comment: @J.R. I do use it, but that curiosity of mine is pushing hard.

Comment: Curiosity is not a good reason to deviate from the simple past. What kind of scenario or context might prompt you to do this?

Comment: @J.R. I'm curious to find it out actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perfect infinitive pushes the need to a *prior* past, a past earlier than another past.

I **need** to have a doctor look at this festering wound. It **is giving** me a great deal of pain.

I **needed to have a doctor** look at that festering wound. It **was giving** me a great deal of pain.

I **needed to have had** a doctor look at that festering wound. It **had been giving** me a great deal of pain. But I did not, and thus I moved on to the astral plane, so that now I can speak to you only via Madame Sosostris.

It sounds better if you change **need to** to **should** but then the time of obligation is the reference time.